# Hide elements in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have `DataGrid` in WPF, item source is 2D array of integers (`DataGrid2D` nuget is used to handle it). Now, how can I hide specific elements? For example, if a cell contains 0, display that cell as empty. I couldn't find anything about it; I'm aware of `StringFormat`, but it's not a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use `DataGridTextColumn` to render your data as a string data type. Binding to such a column will allow using a **custom value converter** to represent the cell contents based on your own logic.

```
<Window x:Class="Solution.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:dataGrid2D="http://gu.se/DataGrid2D">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CellValueConverter x:Key="cellValueConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.Array2D="{Binding Data2D}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding C0, Converter={StaticResource cellValueConverter}}" Header="Col 1"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding C1}" Header="Col 2" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding C2}" Header="Col 3" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public int[,] Data2D { get; set; } = new int[,]
            {
                {0, 3},
                {2, 7},
                {5, 6}
            };
    }
```

Custom value converter `CellValueConverter.cs`:

```
public class CellValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value.ToString() == "0")
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

P.s. I hope I understood it correctly that you're using the [NuGet Package](https://github.com/GuOrg/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D) to handle binding to 2D arrays.

Comment: @AdmiralCat3 did the answer help solving your problem?